# CodePush for Cordova on iOS codePush.sync() doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, code-push

I've followed a few tutorials regarding implementing CodePush so that we can use it to deploy JS updates to a mobile app built for iOS using Cordova.

Namely this one, https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-plugin-code-push

I am currently able to successfully deploy changes to production using the deployment key, but calling `codePush.sync()` on `deviceready` doesn't seem to get any updates and when I check using `code-push deployment ls APP_NAME -k` it reports that no updates have been downloaded. I've deployed with both a mandatory flag and without, and I've tried promoting from staging to production.

I've also attempted to launch a dialog box using the additional parameters in `codePush.sync()` but I couldn't get that to display either. We have specified `<access origin="*" />` in the config.xml file and `cordova-plugin-whitelist` is installed.  The application doesn't stall or break, it just never collects the updates.

I've searched fairly extensively for a resolution but so far all efforts have been fruitless. Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to this. But have you got your solution on this? I'm new to this as well but will try to answer your question.

When you do `code-push deployment ls APP_NAME -k` but the result shows there is no update, have you completed `code-push app add` and `code-push release` before that? `deployment ls APP_NAME -k` will display info of the app deployment only after you do `code-push release`.

Try to change some code in your project, compile the project, and do `code-push release` again. Once the release process is completed, make sure the `deployment ls APP_NAME -k` display the newly updated info before you access the app and check if the app display the update dialog.